# How can I verifiy signed JARs with pure Java?

Tags: java, jar, certificate, code-signing

I don't want to use the `jarsigner -verify`. Is there no JAR util package for my problem?
I just want to verfiy a JAR in pure Java.

Comment: Did you already look at the classes in package java.util.jar?

Comment: I tried JarFile and JarInputStream with the verify flag. But i doesn't work. It works with the jarsigner.

Comment: Have a look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jarsigner.html#Verifying . Verifying looks like a complex procedure. And as I see it, you have to programm this whole process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "jarsigner" is just a small wrapper for a java program that verifies the jar. Inside your JDK there is a "tools.jar" (usally "C:\programs\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\lib\tools.jar" or something like this). Inside this library there is a class "JarSigner" that provides the desired ability. Just put the "tools.jar" on your classpath!

Heres an example program to demonstrate the behaviour

import sun.security.tools.JarSigner;

```
public class TestJarSigner {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  JarSigner signer = new JarSigner();
  signer.run(new String[] { "-verify", "tools.jar" });
 }

}
```

Output is:

```
jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
```

The [sources are availible](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) if you need a deeper understanding of the signing process.